# How can I detec event double tap in android

Tags: android, events, touch-event

How can I detect event double tap in position (x,y) in android?

Answer (score 1):

You can use onDoubleTapListener: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `GestureDetector` and register for double-tap events via [`setOnDoubleTapListener(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#setOnDoubleTapListener%28android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

I think using gesture detector class and overriding onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) should work.

Get the x and y coordinates from the MotionEvent.